# Is it possible for 1 server to serve two different subnets?

Tags: cisco, subnet, packet-tracer, route-server

I was wondering if it is possible for a server to serve two different subnets? I am new to networking so I'm getting confused.

I am using Cisco packet tracer and would like to configure a web and DNS server to be able to respond to requests from two different networks all using the same router. However my server subnet is 255.255.255.0 and one side of the network is also set to that subnet however the other side of my network has a subnet of 255.255.225.128 as I don't want both sides of the network to be able to access each other for security reasons.

Is it possible for my network to work with this set-up? I have tried to research this but haven't found any easy to understand answers for a beginner.

I have of course tried it to see if it works but it fails when I make requests from one side of the network, I just wanted to know if it was possible using a class C IP address for my internal LAN network with different subnets along with a 200.200.1.254 IP for my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `255.255.255.0` and `255.255.255.128` are invalid networks. Maybe you mean `200.200.1.0/25` and `200.200.1.128/25` (masks of `255.255.255.128`)?

If you prevent one of your networks from accessing the other for security reasons, then you cannot access servers on one network from the other network.

It may be possible for your servers to have two NICs, one in each network. You would need to do some configuration on those servers to only allow certain applications to be used on each network. Server configuration is off-topic here, but you could ask about that on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).

Another possibility is that the ACL(s) on the router which block access from one network to the other could have an exception to allow only the specific server addresses and protocols through to the other network. The exact configurations would depend on the specific router model and software version.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's feasible for  server to serve two different subnets

This can be accomplished by Configuring two NIC cards , assign first NIC card with first choosen network subnet as fallow in network adapter properties settings.

`IP address`

`Subnet mask`

`Gateway`

Assign ip address and subnet mask for second NIC cards allowing not to configure default gateway.

Further manually add   route  in persistence routes in server for second NIC traffic .